# Get Oracle Schema

Tags: c#, oracle, provider

Is there any way to retrieve oracle schema in c#?
These are what I need:
        Tables_Name,
        Table Columns_Name,
        Primary Keys,
        Unique Keys,
        Foreign Keys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Table Names](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_2117.htm#i1592091):

```
select * from user_tables
```

[Table Column Names](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_2103.htm#REFRN20277):

```
select * from user_tab_columns
```

[Primary Keys, Unique Keys, Foreign Keys](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_1046.htm#REFRN20047):

```
select * from user_constraints
```

[More generally](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/datadict.htm#CNCPT2140):

```
select * from dictionary
```

to see all the possible system views you can use.

If you want the actual DDL used to create the tables etc you can use [`dbms_metadata.get_ddl`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_metada.htm#i1019414), which returns a CLOB.

For instance:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE','MY_TABLE') from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select from the data dictionary tables in Oracle just like you would any other tables.  Here is a discussion of the data dictionary tables - [Data Dictionary](http://www.dba-oracle.com/concepts/data_dictionary.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DBMS_METADATA` package.
For example, to get the `CREATE` scripts for all the tables, you'd do:

```
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE', u.table_name)
  FROM USER_ALL_TABLES u
```

This way, with a little effort, you can get DDL scripts for the whole schema. And there are more examples on the [`DBMS_METADATA` documetation page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_metada.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I use the `OracleConnection.GetSchema` method.  I wrote myself a helper method to retrieve per table.

```
private class SchemaInfo
{
    public bool Mandatory { get; set; }
    public int MaxLength { get; set; }
}

private Dictionary<string, SchemaInfo> _getSchemaInfo(OracleConnection _cn, string owner, string tableName)
{
    DataTable _dt = _cn.GetSchema("Columns", new string[3] { owner, tableName, null });
    Dictionary<string, SchemaInfo> _dict = new Dictionary<string, SchemaInfo>();
    for (int x = 0; x < _dt.Rows.Count; x++)
    {
        DataRow _r = _dt.Rows[x];
        SchemaInfo _si = new SchemaInfo();
        object maxl = _r.ItemArray[10];
        if (maxl == DBNull.Value) maxl = -1;
        _si.Mandatory = (_r.ItemArray[8].ToString().Equals("N")) ? true : false;
        _si.MaxLength = Convert.ToInt32((maxl ?? 0));
        _dict.Add(_r.ItemArray[2].ToString(), _si);
    }
    return _dict;
}
```

You will have to look up the other elements that are returned to get keys, etc.  I am pretty sure that is available (but could be wrong).

If you want to get Tables, use `Connection.GetSchema("Tables", new string[3] { owner, null, null });`