# How to display all schemas for oracle in C#?

Tags: c#, oracle11g

I would like to retrieve all schemas in oracle and display in a combobox.

I have been researching and knew that I can retrieve through GetSchema().

```
DataTable table = connection.GetSchema();
```

I don't know how to include the schemas in the list.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
return list;
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

See [Get Oracle Schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12270274/get-oracle-schema)

GetSchema() may not be working due to the driver or permissions, but the information at that link should be of use

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I have tried by retrieving the distinct owner from dba_objects.

```
//Show schemas within a server, return a list of string
    public override List<string> showSchema()
    {
        string retrieveSchema = "select distinct owner from dba_objects;";
        List<string> list = new List<string>();

        if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            //Create Command
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(retrieveSchema, conn);
            Console.WriteLine("State: " + conn.State);
            try
            {
                //Create a data reader and Execute the command
                OracleDataReader drOracle = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                //Read the data and store them in the list
                while (drOracle.Read())
                {
                    list.Add(drOracle.GetOracleValue(0).ToString() + "");
                }

                //close Data Reader
                drOracle.Close();
                //close Connection
                this.CloseConnection();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("State: " + conn.State);
            }
        }
        //return list to be displayed
        return list;
    }
```

I can run the sql query but when added in my codes it has ora-00911: invalid character error.