# OleDbParameter and ORA-01461

Tags: c#, oracle, oledbconnection

In Oracle database I have a column with type LONG RAW. I am inserting in this table using OleDb (sorry no other option like ODP.Net). Here is what I am doing,

```
var p = cmd.Parameters.Add(new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter(name: "@attachment", dataType: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.LongVarBinary, size:bytes.Length ));
p.Value = bytes;
```

Here I am getting, `ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column`

I am trying lot of options but failed.

Comment: The database is not configured as a long.  When adding a parameter type in c# it must be the  same type as the database.

Comment: Yes what is the type? what should I pass? how can I convert byte array to long raw

Comment: Check the database.  Login to the database and find out how the table are defined.

Comment: I dont have DBA access but the data type is LONG Raw

Comment: The error message says the database is not Long Raw.  You can use GetSchema() to get tables and columns from the database.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12270274/get-oracle-schema

Comment: consulting your DBA for converting the column's data type to `B(C)LOB` may be preferable if possible. And then, you may try again.

Comment: @jdweng its LONG RAW

Comment: THE ERROR SAYS : can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column.  Maybe you are working with a different datatable or database.

Comment: The bad point is not that you are using the OLE DB provider. The bad point is that you still use `LONG RAW` columns which are hardly supported and deprecated for ages.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit you are right tested with ODP.NET works great but in our old server dont have ODP.NET

Comment: I assume ODP.NET would not help here, you would get the same error. Problem is the `LONG RAW` data type.

Comment: No its working with OracleConnection